# Show that the sequence $f_n(x)=\cos(x/n)$ is Cauchy in the maximum metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $C[-1,1]$ be the space of continuous functions with metric $$\rho(f,g)=\max\{|f(x)-g(x)|: x\in [-1,1]\}\;.$$
Then the sequence of functions $(f_n) :[-1,1] \to \Bbb R$ defined as $(f_n)(x)=\cos(x/n)$.
How to show that this $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in the metric space $(C[-1,1],\rho)$?

---

I have tried to use the definition by looking for the $N$ as follows:

For any $s>0$, there is a $N>0$ such that for all $n,m>N$ we have 
$$\rho((f_n),(f_m))=\max\{|(f_n)(x)-(f_m)(x)|: x \in[-1,1]\} 
            =\max\{|\cos(x/n)-\cos(x/m)|\} <s\;.$$
Since $x$ is between $-1$ and $1$, and $n,m$ are natural numbers, it is easy to see that both 
$\cos(x/n)$ and $\cos(x/m)$ are close to $1$ and close to each other as well from the graph of $y=\cos x$, so this $(f_n)$ is Cauchy.
But how to show rigorously that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy?

Answer (score 2):

Use the factor formulae:

> $|\cos(x/n)-\cos(x/m)|=\big|2\sin(\frac{x}{2m}-\frac{x}{2n})\sin(\frac{x}{2m}+\frac{x}{2n})\big|\le2\big|\frac{x}{2m}-\frac{x}{2n}\big|\big|\frac{x}{2m}+\frac{x}{2n}\big|\le2\big|\frac{1}{2m}-\frac{1}{2n}\big|\big|\frac{1}{2m}+\frac{1}{2n}\big|\le\frac{2}{N^2}$

Then let $N$ be big enough so that $\frac{2}{N^2}\le s$, and we're done.

Comment: Thank you. My question is where does the 8 come from? I just googled the factor formula, should                     |cos(x/n)−cos(x/m)|= | 2 sin[(x/m−x/n)/2] sin[(x/m+x/n)/2] | ?

Comment: @Elvis: Yes, you're right, I missed a factor of 2 - sorry! All fixed now.