# sequences of functions $\cos(\frac{x}{n})$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I have the sequence $(f_n)$ of functions $f_n: [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f_n(x) = \cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$. I need to show that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in the space $(C[-1, 1], d)$ where $d(f, g)= \max\{|f(x)-g(x)| : x \in [-1, 1]\}$. Also, find a function $f:[-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ to which $f$ converges in $(C[-1, 1], d)$

I am not sure that I understand this question. Doesn't $\cos(\frac{x}{n})$ converge to $\cos(0) = 1$? What can you show otherwise?

A function could be just the constant function $f(x) = 1$

Comment: Indeed. It does converge pointwise to $\cos(0) = 1$. If you can show it's Cauchy in that space, then it will show that it converges uniformly to $1$ on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: There is a theorem that says Cauchy iff uniform convergence?

Comment: Well, the sequence would be uniformly Cauchy, since the metric you provided is the uniform norm. It is definitely Cauchy for each fixed $x$ since it converges pointwise for each $x$.

Comment: Check out the bullet pointed theorem in http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_Cauchy_sequence

Comment: But yes, a sequence is uniformly Cauchy iff it converges uniformly since $C[-1,1]$ endowed with the uniform metric is complete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cauchy in metric space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364772/cauchy-in-metric-space)

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, you need to use 
$$ \cos x-\cos y=-2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\sin\frac{x-y}{2}. $$
So
$$ d(f_{n+p},f_n) \le \frac{1}{n(n+p)}\le\frac{1}{n}. $$
Thus $\{f_n(x)\}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: What is $f_{n+p}$ and what is $-f_n$? I've never seen anything with $f_{n+p}$ of $-f_n$ and cauchy sequences before.

Comment: $f_{n+p}$ or $-f_n$

Comment: It should be $f_n$ instead of $-f_n$.